# Problem deploying a non-create-react-app React project onto Github Pages

Tags: reactjs, webpack, error-handling, web-deployment, github-pages

I built a fairly simple react app (but not with create react app but with custom webpack-react setup) and have been struggling to get it onto Github pages. I've followed various (many) guildlines such as adding homepage and deployment scripts in package.json as well as installing gh-pages dependency. Have tried deploying with

```
"gh-pages -d build" or "gh-pages -b master -d build"
```

I think it has to be something about the webpack set up, but I'm not sure how I can work around this. I'm open to using another webpage hosting service if not possible.

```
"homepage": "http://davt49.github.io/calculatorapp",
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"serve": "webpack-dev-server --mode=development",
"build": "webpack -p",
"predeploy": "npm run build",
"deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
},
```

I have "ENOENT: no such file or directory" error when trying to npm run deploy:

```
> basic-react-webpack-setup@1.0.0 predeploy /Users/davidtsui/development/classwork/calculator-app-main
> npm run build


> basic-react-webpack-setup@1.0.0 build /Users/davidtsui/development/classwork/calculator-app-main
> webpack -p

Hash: 187514d9cee9f778efcf Version: webpack 4.46.0 Time: 1308ms Built at: 09/23/2021 2:58:54 PM
               Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names assets/calculator.js   2.48 KiB          [emitted]  
           bundle.js    157 KiB       0  [emitted]  main
          index.html  388 bytes          [emitted]   Entrypoint main = bundle.js  [1] ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/style.scss
8.58 KiB {0} [built]  [4] ./src/assets/calculator.js 6.43 KiB {0} [built]  [5] ./src/app.js 5.54 KiB {0} [built] [10] ./src/style.scss
1.18 KiB {0} [built]
    + 10 hidden modules Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     1 asset
    Entrypoint undefined = index.html
    [0] ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/index.html 540 bytes {0} [built]
    [2] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 472 bytes {0} [built]
    [3] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 497 bytes {0} [built]
        + 1 hidden module

> basic-react-webpack-setup@1.0.0 deploy /Users/davidtsui/development/classwork/calculator-app-main
> gh-pages -d build

ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/davidtsui/development/classwork/calculator-app-main/build' 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE 
npm ERR! errno 1 
npm ERR! basic-react-webpack-setup@1.0.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build` 
npm ERR! Exit status 1 
npm ERR!  
npm ERR! Failed at the basic-react-webpack-setup@1.0.0 deploy script. 
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Appreciate any help at all, and where I can look into. I can share the webpack config file if needed.